# Ctrl + Shift + Del key combination not working in Chromium's New Tab page

Tags: shortcut-keys, chromium

The default key combination for clearing browsing data in Chromium (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>) isn't working when the New Tab page is open and in focus: I press the keys and nothing happens.

If I click the menu icon in Chromium and choose the *Tools* -> *Clear browsing data* option, the dialog shows up. If I'm not looking at the New Tab page, the dialog shows up as expected if I press the same keys.

I'm using Chromium in Ubuntu 12.04 (version `23.0.1271.97-0ubuntu0.12.04.1`). There are no extensions installed and I'm not in incognito mode.

I can use the same key combination on the same machine on Firefox and it works.

How can I fix this?

EDIT: It's been pointed to me that this question is a bug request and should be closed. I have [filed a bug report on the Chromium project site](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=171238).

Comment: Seems like this bug to me [Issue 112874](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112874). I can reproduce this in Google Chrome `24.0.1312.52-r175374` too. I'm voting to close this as bugs are off-topic here as per the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq)

Comment: it works for me, I'm using Chromium 23.0.1271.97

Comment: Just found out the key combination works on any page, ***except*** for the new page tab. Updating the question. @gertvdijk, the bug you linked seems quite similar but not the same.

Comment: @ruda.almeida Yes, fair enough. Good information you just found for a nice new bug report there then! :) (still off-topic imo) It seems there's a lot of fuzz about this shortcut (> 10 issues in one year and even more commits). It seems like a plain regression bug.

Comment: @gertvdijk I didn't know this was a bug on Chromium prior to your indication. Thanks for that. I'm filing a bug report now, feel free to close the question.

Comment: @ruda.almeida Don't forget to link the bug report here for others bumping into this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been pointed to me that this question is a bug request and therefore off-topic and should be closed.

I have filed a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=171238) on the Chromium project site.